# Use XCFramework with objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcframework

I have created one xcframework in Swift Language.
I have marked by .swift class with @objc as well.

I tried to use <frameworkname-Swift.h> in objective c project, But it is showing Module not found error.

Can anyone help with how to use xcframework with Objective-C code.

Comment: Have you use static or dynamic libraries to make xcframework?

Answer (score 7):

It's very important to make your libraries right before making xcframework and starting integrating them to your project.

**Static libraries (.a)**

Your class and its methods should be public and marked with `@objc` to be visible in Objc:

```swift
@objc public class SwiftHelloStatic : NSObject {
    
    @objc static public func hello() {
        print("Hello Static Library!")
    }
}
```

First add your "Objective-c Generated Interface Header" (e.g. SwiftHelloStatic-Swift.h) to "Build Phases > Copy Files", for instance from your destination or from DeviredData folder:

[image]

Build your needed arch (arm64/x86_64) and then you can find "include" folder in your library's one that contains your header:

[image]

Build your xcframework from libraries and headers:

```sh
xcodebuild -create-xcframework 
-library arm64/libSwiftHelloStatic.a -headers arm64/include 
-library x86_64/libSwiftHelloStatic.a -headers x86_64/include 
-output SwiftHelloStatic.xcframework
```

And after verify than your SwiftHelloStatic.xcframework has "Headers" folders inside arch ones:

[image]

Now just drag and drop your xcframework to "General > Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content" with "Do not Embed" because you have static libraries to link.

Last step to set "Build Settings > Header Search Path" to "<your_ destination>/SwiftHelloStatic.xcframework/**" to find your headers.

And finally you can add headers to your objc file:

```objectivec
#import <SwiftHelloStatic/SwiftHelloStatic-Swift.h>

...

[SwiftHelloStatic hello];
```

**Dynamic framework (.framework)**

It's similar to static libraries but simpler because frameworks already have headers. First set `Build Library for Distrubution` to YES and then build your framework for needed archs (arm64, x86_64, ...) and build you xcframework from them e.g.:

```sh
xcodebuild -create-xcframework 
-framework arm64/SwiftHello.framework 
-framework x86_64/SwiftHello.framework 
-output SwiftHello.xcframework
```

Now just drag and drop xcframework to "General > Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content" with "Embed & Sign".

In your objc project you should import your xcframework next way:

```objectivec
#import <SwiftHello/SwiftHello.h>
```

Thats because a valid xcframework contains separate dynamic frameworks for all its target platforms and a needed one from them is linked while compilation so that importing headers to your code is the same as for a regular framework.

Also verify that your classes are accessible in "SwiftHello-Swift.h" e.g.:

```objectivec
SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC10SwiftHello5Hello")
@interface Hello : NSObject
+ (void)hello;
- (nonnull instancetype)init OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
@end
```

Comment: I have tried it importing this way, But no success. 

I can see "FrameworkName-Swift.h" in DerivedSources under derivedData but when i create framework "ios-arm64" and "ios-x86_64-simulator" are visible which containts "library.a" and swiftModue files .

I have tried placing ""FrameworkName-Swift.h"" manually but it also does not work.

I used following commnad to create framework:

xcodebuild -create-xcframework -library build/simulators/libTrackingManager -library build/devices/libTrackingManager -output build/TrackingManager.xcframework

Comment: If you use .a files you should verify that .h headers are present in xcframework and try to set header search paths in your project settings.

Comment: @Tina Please take a look my updated answer.

Comment: @iUrii do I need to mark objc only public classes? and what about public protocols and their methods?

Comment: @iUrii and another question is, Do i need them mark objc if it's dynamic framework(.framework)?

Comment: @AlisherBaigazin You should mark `@objc` all entities classes, protocols, methods etc. that are needed for your public interface of the library.